# Stopping count up timer when restarting game

Tags: c#, timer, unity-game-engine

I've made made the "Roll-a-ball" game from the Unity tutorials on Youtube. However, I've tried program a count up timer, which works fine. The problem is when the game restarts, the timer doesn't, it just continues even though I've set it manually to 00:00.

```
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    count = 0;
    countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString ();
    winText.text = "";
    restartText.text = "";      
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    rb.AddForce(movement * speed);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Vector3 jump = new Vector3(0.0f, 250.0f, 0.0f);

        rb.AddForce(jump);
    }

        if (restart)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.R))
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
            timerText.text = minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + seconds.ToString("00"); //HERE
        }
    }
}


void Update()
{
    if (count < 14)
    {
        minutes = (int)(Time.time / 60f);
        seconds = (int)(Time.time % 60f);
        timerText.text = minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + seconds.ToString("00");
    }
}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Pickup")) {
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        count = count + 1;
        countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString ();
        if (count >= 14){
            winText.text = "You win!";
            restartText.text = "Press 'R' for Restart";
            restart = true;

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only updating the textbox that displays the output, `Time.time` will still be the time from when the game first launched.

What you should do is when you create your PlayerController get the current value of `Time.time` then use that value and subtract it when you are trying to figure out how long the game has been running.

Because you are re-loading the level it should re-initialize the script so you don't need to set the value of the text box when the level restarts.

```
private float _startTime;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    count = 0;
    countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString ();
    winText.text = "";
    restartText.text = "";   
    _startTime = Time.time; //Save the time the game has been running.
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    rb.AddForce(movement * speed);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Vector3 jump = new Vector3(0.0f, 250.0f, 0.0f);

        rb.AddForce(jump);
    }

    if (restart)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.R))
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
        }
    }
}


void Update()
{
    if (count < 14)
    {
        minutes = (int)((Time.time - _startTime) / 60f); //Subtract the time from the total time.
        seconds = (int)((Time.time - _startTime) % 60f);
        timerText.text = minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + seconds.ToString("00");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Time.timeSinceLevelLoad` instead.

Somethig like this:

```
float time = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( secs );
timerText.text = t.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

Comment: The last line can be simplified to `timerText.text = t.ToString(@"mm\:ss");`